# How to manage loading different stylesheets in many different pages

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

I have some PHP in the head tag of my HTML doc (see 3 below), this loads the correct CSS stylesheet dependent on which webpage lander is in the database for that particular domain. The code below is intended for a very large growing group of 100+ domains.

I was wondering if the code I have is most efficient or whether the group can be compacted into an array maybe? This would mean that I would not need so many repeated lines eg.

**1. My 1st attempt at (new) shorter code:**

```
@if(strpos(strtolower($domdata->Lander),'bowling','birthday','cars','etc..') !== false)
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/custom/custom-group.css">
@endif
```

**2. My 2nd attempt at (new) shorter code, but still too long and probably wrong:**

```
@if(strpos(strtolower($domdata->Lander),'bowling') || (strpos(strtolower($domdata->Lander),'birthday') || (strpos(strtolower($domdata->Lander),'cars') !== false)))
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/custom/custom-group.css">
@endif
```

**3. My (existing) long code:**

```
@if(strpos(strtolower($domdata->Lander),'bowling') !== false)
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/custom/custom-group.css">
@endif

@if(strpos(strtolower($domdata->Lander),'birthday') !== false)
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/custom/custom-group.css">
@endif

@if(strpos(strtolower($domdata->Lander),'cars') !== false)
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/custom/custom-group.css">
@endif
```

Comment: Advising on your approach is hard without knowing the full structure of your codebase. Really you should have a separate view file for each page, which would mean hardcoding the stylesheet, or at least setting it in the controller (PHP file which calls your view page). You can even use a shared controller if that makes sense, and identify the correct view file and stylesheet based on the view file to be loaded. How to do this again depends on your system setup.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I would use this approach to code management, however, here is an example of some code reduction as you suggest:

```
$stufftoload = "bowling,birthday,cars,...";
foreach (explode(",", $stufftoload) as $name) {
    if (strpos(strtolower($domdata->Lander), $name) !== false) { 
        echo "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"/css/custom/custom-group.css\">";
        break;
    }
}
```

Lose the "@", as James suggests - you don't want to suppress error messages.  I threw in the break as it seems you are potentially loading the same file repeatedly, though hard to know without knowing what $domdata->Lander looks like.  For example, if $domdata->Lander just had something like "cars" in it, you would probably do something like:

```
$stufftoload = "bowling,birthday,cars,...";
if (strpos($stufftoload, strtolower($domdata->Lander)) !== false) { 
    echo "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"/css/custom/custom-group.css\">";
}
```